# Where can I read about non-principal obstruction theory?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, obstruction-theory

Most treatments of obstruction theory assume a *principal* Postnikov tower. I have the vague sense that if one uses cohomology with local coefficients, one does not need to make any assumptions on one's Postnikov tower. I've always assumed that if I ever needed this, I could look it up in a standard reference. That day has come, and I can't seem to find this theory in Hatcher, Whitehead, or Spanier.

Whitehead's *Elements of Homotopy Theory* comes closest -- Chapter VI.5 does some kind of obstruction theory with local coefficients, but even there, right after Theorem 5.2, he makes some kind of simplicity assumption about his fibration.

**Questions:**

1. Does there really exist a form of obstruction theory which works for an *arbitrary* fibration, with no principality or simplicity assumptions?
2. If so, where can I read about it?
3. If not, is there at least a form of obstruction theory which works for any fibration with, say, simply-connected fibers? The assumptions I've come across all seem to require that the fundamental group of the codomain acts trivially on some homotopy groups of the fiber, so that connectivity assumptions on the fiber don't seem to be enough for the theory to work.

Ideally, I'd like a full relative obstruction theory -- i.e. a theory of finding homotopy-coherent lifts for any commutative square.

Comment: Have you looked at Olum's "Obstructions to extensions and homotopies" paper? Apparently it does obstruction theory for fibrations with non-simple fibers.

Comment: @MarkGrant I see, thanks. I now realize that my question is really a duplicate of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31147/obstruction-theory-for-non-simple-spaces?rq=1).

Comment: it's overkill, but if you just want *some* reference there is HTT.7.2.2.26, and its corollary 7.2.2.27, which you can apply in the case $\mathcal{X}=\mathsf{Spaces}_{/X}$ to the n-gerbe obtained by pulling back $Y_{\le n}$ along an already constructed map $X \to Y_{\le n-1}$.

Comment: @DylanWilson Thanks! I think being able to see the ideas packaged in multiple different ways will be very helpful for me!

Comment: The book by H.-J. Baues on obstruction theory might also be helpful.